# can't access wamp server localhost

Tags: php, apache, wamp, bitnami

I'm getting the 404 not found error whn I'm trying to access local host from another computer.
precisely this error appears when i write the link my server's ip address/localhost in my browser

also the bitnami wamp stack shows the port no. of apache as 81 but in the conf file the command is to Listen 80(is this a problem?)
i was able to ping the computer(my mobile pho) from the server(my laptop)

the following is the error log of the apache server:

```
[Tue Oct 31 00:10:36.632302 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9052:tid 604] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 00:10:37.625006 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9052:tid 604] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 00:10:37.717072 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9052:tid 604] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:32.245340 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:32.786715 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.30-2/apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:32.935872 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.091663 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.091663 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  8 2016 11:33:36
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.091663 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.30-2/apache2 -f C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.091663 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5752
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.622918 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5752:tid 568] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.857279 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5752:tid 568] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:03:41.872905 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5752:tid 568] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:51.841032 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:53.848176 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5752:tid 568] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:53.951493 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3156:tid 648] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5752 exited successfully.
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:57.819914 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:58.280480 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:59.524187 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:59.524187 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  8 2016 11:33:36
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:59.524187 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.30-2/apache2 -f C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Tue Oct 31 10:45:59.530192 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4892
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:00.558463 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4892:tid 540] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:00.937326 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4892:tid 540] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:00.986568 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4892:tid 540] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:52.148891 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:54.150007 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4892:tid 540] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:54.195043 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11880:tid 112] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4892 exited successfully.
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:55.653960 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:56.104259 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:56.155062 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:56.155062 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  8 2016 11:33:36
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:56.155062 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.30-2/apache2 -f C:\\Bitnami\\WAMPST~1.30-\\apache2\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:56.161067 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9680:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12336
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:57.175153 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 12336:tid 532] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:57.572633 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 12336:tid 532] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 31 10:46:57.620980 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12336:tid 532] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Few things, port should be 80. Check Skype and Teamviewer if already installed change their port.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install the Bitnami WAMP Stack using the default ports 80/443 you must ensure you don't have any server listening in the port 80.

In case you installed the Stack and you had one server on one of those ports, the installer detects that and configure Apache to listen on alternative port such as 81. Therefore, you need to access to http://localhost:81 in order to access the Apache Web Server include in the Stack. If you're accessing your server from a different computer in the same network please check your Windows Firewall configuration. The firewall could be blocking the web requests. See the link below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/#how-to-open-ports-for-remote-access

Answer (score 0):

on windows start cmd as an administrator

type

```
net stop http
```

then hit yes it will hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: Help fix what problem? And by doing this what will the OP actually be changing?

Comment: I stupidly ran this from frustration (without thought) and it stopped every service except http. AVOID